# how to add UIActivityIndicator to window as subview..?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

i have to add activity indicator to UITableViewController view since table view height can wary as number of rows increases its not possible to activity indicator display at center. 
So i think to add it as subview to window and bring it front but when i try

[[self view] window] 
  it giving nil,
i tried even

[[[self view] superView] window] then also it giving nil only.

how to overcome this...

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
    // start our activity spinner
    if ( self.spinner == nil ) {
        self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        self.spinner.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/3);
        [self.view addSubview:self.spinner];    
    }
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
```